# Triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am newbie in SQL.I am reading Triggers created two trigger on a table.Below is my triggers-

```
CREATE trigger Test_TRIGGER_FOR
ON TEST_TABLE
for Insert
AS
if((Select ID from TEST_TABLE) =( Select ID from INSERTED))
BEGIN
PRINT 'you have successful using FOR'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'ERROR AFTER'
END

CREATE trigger Test_TRIGGER_AFTER
ON TEST_TABLE
AFTER Insert
AS
if((Select ID from TEST_TABLE) =( Select ID from INSERTED))
BEGIN
PRINT 'you have successful using AFTER'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'ERROR AFTER'
END
```

I had created successfully Triggers but when I insert data in my table I am getting following error-

**Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test_TRIGGER_FOR, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.**

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not ever use triggers to return print staments. They are not run most of the time in a context where a print statement would be seen. Triggers exist for doing data processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is becase you are doing a `SELECT ID FROM TEST_TABLE` which is returning multiple records.  You need to add a `WHERE` clause to this in order to reduce it to 1 record for your test to succeed.

You could try something like:

```
DECLARE @id int;
SELECT @id = ID from INSERTED;

SELECT ID
  FROM TEST_TABLE
 WHERE ID = @id;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'you have successful using FOR' 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'ERROR AFTER' 
END
```

Comment: It's important to note, however, that the INSERTED pseudo table can *also* contain multiple rows. And the above will error on a default SQL 2008 server, since you're returning a result set from within a trigger.

Comment: Incorrect example and you should not promote this incorrect technique of writing triggers. Triggers must assume that inserted or deleted will contain multiple rows. YOU should under no circumstances ever be doing this: SELECT  [ID] FROM inserted. You willnot get correct results if multiple records are inserted. Any trigger you have written with this technique needs an immediate rewrite as you are messing with data integrity here.  This example is so bad that it should be deleted or changed to a correct trigger example for the poster to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

On the line

```
if((Select ID from TEST_TABLE) =( Select ID from INSERTED))
```

the `(Select ID from TEST_TABLE)` will return more that one value if there are more than 1 entry in the table, which is not permitted in such a sub select.

It is slightly unclear what you are trying to do here though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with both triggers is this line:

```
if((Select ID from TEST_TABLE) =( Select ID from INSERTED))
```

It's unclear what you're trying to test for here, but both the TEST_TABLE and INSERTED tables can contain multiple rows.

Comment: thanks Damien.Yes it was a silly mistake.I was trying to do both FOR and AFTER use on the same table:)